# 2D discrete function minimums based on ListContourPlot

Tags: mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation

A have 2D function defined on some square (e.g. `{x, 1, 10}`, `{y, 1, 10}` with step 1). It's represented via array, e.g.: `RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]`. And I need to detect centers of "minimum areas" in the `ListContourPlot[]` of this data (probably using some threshold). For example, one of my samples has next representation and I want to find coordinates of red points:

[image]

I know I can go for converting the plot to the image and using some image-based segmentation to locate these areas and to define their centres, but it's too time-consuming approach (a have a lot of such samples).

So the question is: how do I find such points by analyzing "raw" data from my array (the faster - the better).

**NB**: there may be multiple target areas in different locations - I need them all...

Comment: `FindMinimum[{f[x,y], 6 <= x <= 10, 8 <= y <= 10}, {x, y}]` and `FindMinimum[{f[x,y], 6 <= x <= 10, 6 <= y <= 8}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @Feyre, I've updated the question: I don't have f[x,y] - I have an array. And also I don't know the borders of the target area, so I can't use constraints like `6 <= x <= 10` or `8 <= y <= 10`.

Comment: If you run `{Position[f = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], min = Min@f], min}` you generate an array in `f`, and print its minimum value and all the positions where this value is achieved.

Comment: Are you asking for the centroid of the area enclosed by the minimum contour?  That is going to be a function of the contour algorithm ( interpolation, selection of contour intervals, etc ), so you can not get it from the raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];

plot = ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 5];
p1 = RegionCentroid[
   Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x_] :> Polygon[x], Infinity][[-1]]];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[p1]}]]
```

[image]

when you have multiple regions at the lowest level you'll need to manually take the 'last n' results from `Cases`:

```
plot = ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 5];
pts = RegionCentroid /@ 
   Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x_] :> Polygon[x], Infinity][[-9 ;;]];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

The green marker is the minimum for the interpolation function found by

```
Last@Quiet@
  FindMinimum[
   Interpolation[Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, data, {2}], 1], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 3][x, y], {x, y}]
```

as you see its a little different.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! But still... Is there any way to obtain the SAME result without plotting? I mean... Mathematica does the 'levels' computation somehow (detects regions with different colors on the plot). Is it possible to perform such computations manually on the input data (directly) and then detect target points? If no, I'll accept this answer as a correct one anyway. I see the example with Interpolation and FindMinimum, but it finds only one point and the interpolation itself is quite time-consumable. Is there any "multi-point discrete algorithm"?

Comment: you would basically need to reverse engineer the contour algorithm.  If you want the "Real" minima for each contour region you can try feeding each centroid point as an initial point for `FindMinimum`. You might also specify more contours on the plot.